# selecting non-english character using oracle client in c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying execute query in C# to store the data in DataTable. however the database has some non-English character(AR8MSWIN1256). the result of the select query returns (????)

my code :

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection con = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection();
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder ocsb = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
                ocsb.Password = "password";
                ocsb.UserID = "username";
                ocsb.DataSource = "datasource";
                ocsb.Unicode = true;

    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand cmd = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(
                "SELECT 'ب' LETTER  FROM DUAL", con);

                Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

the result is (?)

can anyone help with this issue. thank you

Comment: Try replacing 'ب' with chr(200)..

Comment: CHR(200) returns error: ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

Comment: Does your console support your db characterset? What does chcp return?

Comment: it returns Active code page: 437

Comment: are you on Windows? Is your `nls_lang` set correctly?

Comment: Does it work when you run `chcp 1256` before you execute the program?

Comment: What is your `NLS_LANG` environment settings?

Comment: Namespace `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for ages, you should not use it. If may not support Arabic characters, better try a supported driver.